# Closed-form solution for $x^a = (1-x)^{1-a}\cdot b$ with $0 < a < 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, closed-form

How can I tell if $x^a = (1-x)^{1-a} \cdot b$ has a closed form solution for $x$, assuming $0<a<1$. It does in the case of $a=\frac{1}{2}$, but is this the only case?

Computer algebra systems don't seem to be helping.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

Maple also finds closed form solutions for  $a = \frac 1 3,  \frac 1 4, \frac 2 3, \frac 3 4, \frac 2 5, \frac 3 5$...

Wolfram Alpha online also get them: cf [for $a=\frac 13$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20(x%5E(1%2F3)%3D(1-x)%5E(1-(1%2F3))*b%2Cx)%3B&t=crmtb01) and [for $a = \frac 1 4$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%28x%5E%281%2F4%29%3D%281-x%29%5E%281-%281%2F4%29%29*b%2Cx%29%3B).

The 2 shortest answers:
[image]

Comment: This does answer the question "It does in the case of a=1/2, but is this the only case?"

Comment: It would improve the answer if you listed a few of the closed form solutions.

Comment: Done for two. ( I'm sure there is a rule against the length that would require including the other answers :-D )